# How to create a new line from a specific point in bash?

Tags: bash

I want to create a new line from '{'. Any sentence after '{' needs to be in a new line.

Currrent output:

```
void logical_jmp(int loc) { int branch_jmp(int loc) {
```

Required output:

```
void logical_jmp(int loc)

int branch_jmp(int loc)
```

This is the task:
find all the C function given a directory. Your script will have to recursively look through the directory and find all .c files and output the functions contained within them.

My code:

```
dirName=$1

if [[ -d $dirName ]]; then

    cfile=$(find $dirName -type f -name "*.c"|sort -n)

    for i in $cfile; do
        echo $i:
        if grep -q -E "^void|^int|^FILE*" $i; 
        then
            func=$(cat $i |grep -E "^void|^int|^FILE*"|sed 's/[{$] */\n/g')         
            echo $func
            echo
        else
            echo Unable to find any functions
        fi              
    done        
else
    echo file is not a directory
fi
```

Comment: How are you going to handle the multiple closing `'}'` that will be left dangling?

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is always advisable to post your samples in CODE TAGS rather than images, please do so in your post.

Comment: Don't ask with photos or screenshots. Put your code here. The edit tool provides buttons for markup.

Answer (score 2):

Simple `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '{gsub(/{ |{/,ORS)} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: Did not work. this is what i working on                                  
             func=$(cat $i |grep -E "^void|^int|^FILE*")   
   echo $func
   echo                                                                                                       so the output of func is what the above picture was.

Comment: @zigzag, you have to provide all details about your question then, all your requirements, please do so. I given solution on your simple statement to substitute `{` with new line, let us know on same?

Comment: @zigzag, try my edited code now and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: should i use $func for input_file. i tried getting this error message "awk: fatal: cannot open file `int' for reading (No such file or directory)" int changes to void for files with void in it

Comment: @zigzag, ok whatever your output is coming from previous command pipe it to `awk` like `previous_command | `awk.....` let me know how it goes then?

Comment: it just printed same as before but without {

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr '{' '\n' | sed 's/^//'`.
Perhaps you can take another approach with

```
grep -Eo "^(void|char|int)[^(]+\([^)]*\)" *.c
```

This regular expression assumes all functions are of type void, char or int, the type starting at the first position of the line and have the characters `()`in the line.
You can modify the regular expression to meet your requirements.